# Method taking interface as a parameter inside interface

Tags: go, struct, interface

I am declcaring an interface in go

```
type comparable interface {
GetKey() float32
Compare(comparable) int
```

}

and implementing this interface by creating this structure

```
type Note struct {
id       int
text     string
priority float32
```

}

```
func (note Note) GetKey() float32 {
return note.priority
```

}

```
func (note Note) Compare(note2 Note) int {
if note.priority < note2.priority {
    return -1
} else if note.priority > note2.priority {
    return 1
} else {
    return 0
}
```

}

But when I am passing note object into a function which accepts comparable interface as a parameter I am getting "Wrong type for method compare" error.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not implementing `comparable` since you use `Note` in compare method not `comparable`. `Compare(note2 Note)` is not same as `Compare(comparable)`.

Use `comparable` in Compare method to implement `comaprable` interface

```
func (note Note) Compare(note2 comparable) int {
    if note.GetKey()< note2.GetKey() {
        return -1
    } else if note.GetKey()> note2.GetKey() {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You declared `comparable` as having a method with signature `Compare(comparable) int`.

So `func (note Note) Compare(note2 Note)` ought to be `func (note Note) Compare(note2 comparable)`, to match the interface.

Otherwise, you're not implementing the same interface. To implement `comparable`, your `Compare` method needs to take any `comparable`, but the one you declared for `Note` takes only `Note`, and not any comparable. It's a different method.

Here's a modified-to-work, minimal example based on your code: https://play.golang.org/p/ajH1s5gbGcQ